# CSS Using Position and top

Tags: html, css

I have some old VB code where it is calling a function to return values and then I am displaying a table.  the function is returning values on the right site and the code has html where it is displaying on the left side.

There is a large space after the left text and the table.  What I did to get around it was to add a  tag with a style in it (shown below).  The issue is after the end of the Div the next text is spaced by 70 pixels.

```
<canned code from a function>

<div style="position:relative; top:-70px">
<table>
<tr>
...
</tr>
<table>
```

If I do not put the below in there will be a huge space after the above table.

```
    <div style="position:relative; top:-70px">
         This text will appear after the table and if I do not copy the style info there will be a lot of white space.
    .
    .
    </div>
```

I tried Clear and a few other items but seems like the only solution would be to copy the style and I do not want to use this all over the old ugly VB code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the same amount of negative bottom margin `margin-bottom: -70px;`

```
<div style="position:relative; top:-70px; margin-bottom: -70px;">
     This text will appear after the table and if I do not copy the style info there will be a lot of white space.
.
.
</div>
```

Comment: This worked Great, I did add the "margin-bottom: -70px;" to the top section of the code where the DIV was in the Table, Not in the area where the text stated " This text will appear..."